# NoSuchJobException when running a job programmatically in Spring Batch

Tags: spring, configuration, spring-batch, jobs

I have a Job running on startup. I want to run this job programmatically at a particular point of my application, not when I start my app.

When running on startup I have no problem, but I got a "NoSuchJobException" (`No job configuration with the name [importCityFileJob] was registered`) when I try to run it programmatically.

After looking on the web, I think it's a problem related to JobRegistry, but I don't know how to solve it.

Note : my whole batch configuration is set programmatically, I don't use any XML file to configure my batch and my job. That's a big part of my problem while I lack the examples...

Here is my code to run the Job :

```
public String runBatch() {
    try {
        JobLauncher launcher = new SimpleJobLauncher();
        JobLocator locator = new MapJobRegistry();
        Job job = locator.getJob("importCityFileJob");
        JobParameters jobParameters = new JobParameters(); // ... ?
        launcher.run(job, jobParameters);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        System.out.println("Something went wrong");
    }
    return "Job is running";
}
```

My Job declaration :

```
@Bean
public Job importCityFileJob(JobBuilderFactory jobs, Step step) {
    return jobs.get("importFileJob").incrementer(new RunIdIncrementer()).flow(step).end().build();
}
```

(I tried to replace `importCityFileJob` by `importFileJob` in my runBatch method, but it didn't work)

My BatchConfiguration file contains the job declaration above, a step declaration, the itemReader/itemWriter/itemProcessor, and that's all.
I use the `@EnableBatchProcessing` annotation.

I'm new to Spring Batch & I'm stuck on this problem. Any help would be welcome.

Thanks

---

Edit : I've solved my problem. I wrote my solution in the answers

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A `JobRegistry` won't populate itself.  In your example, you're creating a new instance, then trying to get the job from it without having registered it in the first place.  Typically, the `JobRegistry` is configured as a bean along with an `AutomaticJobRegistrar` that will load all jobs into the registrar on startup.  That doesn't mean they will be executed, just registered so they can be located later.

If you're using Java configuration, this should happen automatically using the `@EnableBatchProcessing` annotation.  With that annotation, you'd just inject the provided `JobRegistry` and the jobs should already be there.

You can read more about the `@EnableBatchProcessing` in the documentation here: http://docs.spring.io/spring-batch/apidocs/org/springframework/batch/core/configuration/annotation/EnableBatchProcessing.html

You can also read about the `AutomaticJobRegistrar` in the documentation here: http://docs.spring.io/spring-batch/apidocs/org/springframework/batch/core/configuration/support/AutomaticJobRegistrar.html

Comment: Thank you for the explanation.
I was already using the `@EnableBatchProcessing` annotation (after reading the documentation, I've only added the `modular=true` part), but the AutomaticJobRegistrar didn't work, I still had the error. Should I add something more in my batch configuration, or the AutomaticJobRegistrar is supposed to be already here if I use `@EnableBatchProcessing(modular=true)` ?
It's just a question to understand what happen, while I've solved my problem using a JobRegistryBeanPostProcessor.

Answer (score 32):

Here is what I had to do to fix my problem:

Add the following Bean to the BatchConfiguration :

```
@Bean
public JobRegistryBeanPostProcessor jobRegistryBeanPostProcessor(JobRegistry jobRegistry) {
    JobRegistryBeanPostProcessor jobRegistryBeanPostProcessor = new JobRegistryBeanPostProcessor();
    jobRegistryBeanPostProcessor.setJobRegistry(jobRegistry);
    return jobRegistryBeanPostProcessor;
}
```

Replace the JobLocator by an `@Autowired` JobRegistry, and use the `@Autowired` JobLauncher instead of creating one. My run method now have the following code :

```
@Autowired
private JobRegistry jobRegistry;

@Autowired
private JobLauncher launcher;

public String runBatch() {
    try {
        Job job = jobRegistry.getJob("importCityFileJob");
        JobParameters jobParameters = new JobParameters();
        launcher.run(job, jobParameters);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        System.out.println("Something went wrong");
    }
    return "OK";
}
```

I hope it will help someone.

Comment: Indeed this is the answer to the problem. At startup it shows: "DEBUG [main] JobRegistryBeanPostProcessor : Registering job: JobName". Should't this happen automatically? Thank you.

Comment: This seems to work this is the documentation for this "Include a bean of this type along with your job configuration, and use the same JobRegistry as a JobLocator when you need to locate a Job to launch."

Answer (score 4):

I could not find the correct answer on this page. In my case the spring batch jobs were configured in a different configuration class not annotated with @EnableBatchProcessing. In that case you need to add the Job to the JobRegistry:

```
import org.springframework.batch.core.Job;
import org.springframework.batch.core.configuration.DuplicateJobException;
import org.springframework.batch.core.configuration.JobRegistry;
import org.springframework.batch.core.configuration.annotation.JobBuilderFactory;
import org.springframework.batch.core.configuration.support.ReferenceJobFactory;
import org.springframework.batch.core.job.flow.Flow;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;

@Configuration
public class MyBatchJobConfigurations {

    @Bean
    public Job myCountBatchJob(final JobBuilderFactory jobFactory, final JobRegistry jobRegistry, final Flow myJobFlow)
        throws DuplicateJobException {
      final Job countJob = jobFactory.get("myCountBatchJob")
            .start(myJobFlow)
            .end().build();
      ReferenceJobFactory referenceJobFactory = new ReferenceJobFactory(countJob);
      jobRegistry.register(referenceJobFactory);
      return countJob;
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Adding the following bean in the applicationContext.xml resolved the problem for me

```
<bean class="org.springframework.batch.core.configuration.support.JobRegistryBeanPostProcessor">
    <property name="jobRegistry" ref="jobRegistry" />
</bean>
```

I also have this entry in the applicationContext.xml

```
<bean id="jobRegistry"
    class="org.springframework.batch.core.configuration.support.MapJobRegistry" />
```

Answer (score 0):

another solution:

rename the method name **"importCityFileJob"** to **"job"**:

```
@Bean
public Job job(JobBuilderFactory jobs, Step step) {
    return jobs.get("importFileJob").incrementer(new RunIdIncrementer()).flow(step).end().build();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
@EnableBatchProcessing
@Configuration
public class SpringBatchCommon {

  @Bean
  public JobRegistryBeanPostProcessor jobRegistryBeanPostProcessor(JobRegistry jobRegistry) {
    JobRegistryBeanPostProcessor postProcessor = new JobRegistryBeanPostProcessor();
    postProcessor.setJobRegistry(jobRegistry);
    return postProcessor;
  }
}
```

Set the JobRegistry in the JobRegistryBeanPostProcessor , after that you can autowire the JobLauncher and the JobLocator

```
     Job job = jobLocator.getJob("importFileJob");
     JobParametersBuilder jobBuilder = new JobParametersBuilder();
     //set any parameters if required
     jobLauncher.run(job, jobBuilder.toJobParameters()
```